# finding the mode of the user-input values for java programming

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Code {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Double num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, sum, avg, max, min, mode;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
    num1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the seond number:");
    num2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the third number:");
    num3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the fourth number:");
    num4 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the fifth number:");
    num5 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    keyboard.close();

    double[] num = new double[5]; // array named num is declared with 5 variables
    num[0] = num1;
    num[1] = num2;
    num[2] = num3;
    num[3] = num4;
    num[4] = num5;
    Arrays.sort(num);



    sum = (double)(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5);
    avg = (double)(sum/5);
    max = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(num1, num2),num3),num4),num5);
    min = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(num1, num2),num3),num4),num5);

    System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
    System.out.println("Avg:" + avg);
    System.out.println("Max:" + max);
    System.out.println("Min:" + min);
    System.out.println("Median:" + num[2]);

    }
}
```

Hello guys.
I have the following code on the top.
I have yet to put the code for finding the mode (most frequently appeared user-input number and its occurence).
Could someone help me with this please?

===========================================================================================
Added codes for mod as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Code {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Double num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, sum, avg, max, min;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
    num1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the seond number:");
    num2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the third number:");
    num3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the fourth number:");
    num4 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the fifth number:");
    num5 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    keyboard.close();

    double[] num = new double[5]; // array named num is declared with 5 variables
    num[0] = num1;
    num[1] = num2;
    num[2] = num3;
    num[3] = num4;
    num[4] = num5;
    Arrays.sort(num);

    double[] data = {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5};
    int mode = 0;
    int[] index = new int[999];
    int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        index[(int) data[i]]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++){
        if(maximum < index[i]){
            maximum = index[i];
            mode = i;
        }
    }

    sum = (double)(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5);
    avg = (double)(sum/5);
    max = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(num1, num2),num3),num4),num5);
    min = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(num1, num2),num3),num4),num5);

    System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
    System.out.println("Avg:" + avg);
    System.out.println("Max:" + max);
    System.out.println("Min:" + min);
    System.out.println("Median:" + num[2]);
    System.out.println("Mode:" + mode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Map implementation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static double mode(Double[] values) {

    List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(values);
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int count = 0;
    double mode = 0;
    for(Double i: list) {
        count = Collections.frequency(list, i);
        if(count > max) {
            max = count;
            mode = i;
        }
    }
    return mode;  
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping. but really trying to do the map interface for this one.